# Is there a way to set 2 different passwords to unlock an Android device?

Tags: android

I am developing an app, and I'd like to know if there is a way to do that. I need the that phone may be unlocked using two different passowrds or pins and identify which one has unlocked it.

I don't know if android allows that, but I hope you can tell me.

Thanks!